# Ambiguous grammar when parsing boolean expressions with Peg.js

Tags: javascript, peg

I'm writing a parser that generates an abstract syntax tree from boolean expressions.

I have the following Peg.js grammar that supports `^` and `∨`, as `&` and `|` respectively:

```
start
  = operation

// optional whitespace
_  = [ \t\r\n]*

operation "operation"
  = "("? _ left:(operand / operation) _ operator:operator _ right:(operand / operation) _  ")"?
  {
    return {
      operation: operator,
      between: [ left, right ]
    };
  }

operator "operator"
  = operator:["&"|"|"]  
  {
    return operator;
  }

operand "operand"
  = operand:[a-z]
  { 
    return { operand: operand };
  }
```

It successfully parses expressions like `a & b` and `a & (b | c)`, however it fails if the expression starts with an operation:

```
(a | b) & c
Line 1, column 8: Expected end of input but " " found.
```

The expression gets parsed correctly if I surround it with parenthesis:

```
((a | b) & c)
```

My guess is that Peg.js is only taking `(a | b)` as an operation, instead of an operand of the parent operation, thus failing when seeing the `& c`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6):

Your operation rule says the brackets are optional but having one does not enforce the other to be there. E.g., `(a & b` is parsed successfully.

You need to break it up into smaller parts. The separate rules for `and` and `or` are to allow operator precedence to do its trick.

Try this:

```
start
  = sentence

sentence
  = orSentence

orSentence
  = lhs:andSentence __ '|' __ rhs:orSentence { return { operation: '|', between: [lhs, rhs] }; }
  / andSentence

andSentence
  = lhs:primarySentence __ '&' __ rhs:andSentence { return { operation: '&', between: [lhs, rhs] }; }
  / primarySentence

primarySentence
  = '(' _ sentence:sentence _ ')' { return sentence; }
  / operand

operand
  = operand:[a-z] { return { operand: operand }; }

_ "optionalWhiteSpace"
  = whiteSpace *

__ "mandatoryWhiteSpace"
  = whiteSpace +

whiteSpace
  = [ \t\n\r]+
```